# Getting a Tikz Editor to Work

Tags: tikz-pgf

Okay. I found this [Tikz editor](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbQLoBoQygc3ktAXyA), but I am having trouble getting it to render when I copy and paste the code. Here is my setup (it looks pretty awful...):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart} \usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath,graphicx,amssymb,amsthm} \usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{30} 
 \usepackage{comment} \usepackage{tikz}

\providecommand{\U}[1]{\protect\rule{.1in}{.1in}} %EndMSIPreambleData
\addtolength{\textheight}{10mm} \addtolength{\textwidth}{25mm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-15mm}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-15mm}  \addtolength{\topmargin}{-10mm}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\newtheorem{set}{set}[section] \newtheorem{theorem}[set]{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{acknowledgement}[set]{Acknowledgement}
\newtheorem{algorithm}[set]{Algorithm} \newtheorem{axiom}[set]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{case}[set]{Case} \newtheorem{claim}[set]{Claim}
\newtheorem{conclusion}[set]{Conclusion}
\newtheorem{condition}[set]{Condition}
\newtheorem{conjecture}[set]{Conjecture}
\newtheorem{corollary}[set]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{criterion}[set]{Criterion}
\newtheorem{definition}[set]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[set]{Example}
\newtheorem{exercise}[set]{Exercise} \newtheorem{lemma}[set]{Lemma}
\newtheorem*{lemma*}{Lemma} \newtheorem{notation}[set]{Notation}
\newtheorem{problem}[set]{Problem} \newtheorem*{problem*}{Problem}
\newtheorem{proposition}[set]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{remark}[set]{Remark} \newtheorem{solution}[set]{Solution}
\newtheorem{summary}[set]{Summary} \newcommand{\h}{\mathcal{H}}
\newcommand{\abs}[1]{\left\vert#1\right\vert}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\rad}{\text{rad }} \allowdisplaybreaks[4]

\title{} 
\author{} \date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{problem*} Show that a commutative diagram

%
https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBpiBdUkANwEMAbAVxiRBAF9T1Nd9CUARnJVajFm07cQGbHgJEATCOr1mrRCADCAfWBgA1II5Sec-ktKLRaiZoCiew8dMze8gSSs3xG9lzM+BSFvVV9JALdzYOQAZlJBH3U2AEEnE0jZIM8AFhUxZM0AIR1CTPcLFDzrMMKQABFS1yyPIgBWfNs-XTLpFsrkDpqCuxBHXsDWlAA2BKTRtP0AWhdy6M8Adk7w4qcVjL6KmK3hrrZG5dXD9aIADlCRv2ajz3vKWtHnm5QATm26r7ZIh-U47fyiGBQADm8CIoAAZgAnCAAWyQZBAOAgSGEIAYWDAfigEBwOEhIGoAAsYHQoGxIITXEjUTjqFikMpHmwADrcxhoSl0JxGA4I5FoxCc9mIeJ4ugAIxgDAACi82AwYPCcBSuZp4cKrmKWYg8pjsYgOniCUSSWS6VSaXTNAzWJFmRLLdLZWdNLzFTghfoRTqGAqlarviBEVgoZTtW7xUhZdLZnLFSq1Zpo7HtR8-JSmgnjVLzamfSAoU1qKH0xGgZoNVqmYnEKnpVtdSAANaF6TupBt833NPhzNRmNxnXlgBWvaNEo70r+nd5-MFVZHGcjjfjfZbw+lggx5b9MAD6RDYa39fHOebxsXQ7zPO5ULoKJRQomIH7iGXh+PMF9W-X9-3NQRcXLStLlFH8WyPNlwMgsECxg+8JQgxCcU5csezQosMNxQ9vTBWc0OrK86ymW9JwInFk3A00a1HSNs0nZ9fW5f1AzAfZ0OwrDEEES0Tz5BgBR4vi6KEz1wNTfFGU0YlSXJB1aXpAhXT3Y1BFNQ8OwUm0VPtEBqXU51NJ1AMsAYDTGQo2sxx3fihJLeiHJYm9nI4kBeTfD9JNWCgOCAA
\begin{tikzcd} {} \arrow[r, no head, dotted] & {} \arrow[r,
"\alpha_{n+1}"] & C_{n+1} \arrow[dd, "f_{n+1}"] \arrow[rd, "g_n"] &   
& B_n \arrow[r, "\alpha_n"] \arrow[dd, "\gamma_n"] & C_n \arrow[dd,
"f_n"] \arrow[rd, "g_{n-1}"] &                                        
& B_{n-1} \arrow[r, "\alpha_{n-1}"] \arrow[dd, "\gamma_{n-1}"] & {}
\arrow[r, no head, dotted] & {} \\
                              &                              &                                                 & A_{n} \arrow[ru, "k_n"] \arrow[rd, "j_n"'] &                        
&                                             & A_{n-1} \arrow[ru,
"k_{n-1}"] \arrow[rd, "j_{n-1}"'] &                                   
&                               &    \\ {} \arrow[r, no head, dotted]
& {} \arrow[r, "\beta_{n+1}"'] & E_{n+1} \arrow[ru, "h_n"']           
&                                            & D_n \arrow[r,
"\beta_{n}"']                      & E_n \arrow[ru, "h_{n-1}"]        
&                                                      & D_{n-1}
\arrow[r, "\beta_{n-1}"']                            & {} \arrow[r, no
head, dotted] & {} \end{tikzcd}

with the two sequences across the top and bottom exact, gives rise to
an exact sequence where the maps are obtained from those in the
previous diagram in the obvious way, except that $B_n \to C_n \oplus
D_n$ has a minus sign in one coordinate.  \end{problem*}

\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong? [Here](https://tikzcd.yichuanshen.de/#N4Igdg9gJgpgziAXAbVABwnAlgFyxMJZABgBpiBdUkANwEMAbAVxiRBAF9T1Nd9CUARnJVajFm07cQGbHgJEATCOr1mrRCADCAfWBgA1II5Sec-ktKLRaiZoCiew8dMze8gSSs3xG9lzM+BSFvVV9JALdzYOQAZlJBH3U2AEEnE0jZIM8AFhUxZM0AIR1CTPcLFDzrMMKQABFS1yyPIgBWfNs-XTLpFsrkDpqCuxBHXsDWlAA2BKTRtP0AWhdy6M8Adk7w4qcVjL6KmK3hrrZG5dXD9aIADlCRv2ajz3vKWtHnm5QATm26r7ZIh-U47fyiGBQADm8CIoAAZgAnCAAWyQZBAOAgSGEIAYWDAfigEBwOEhIGoAAsYHQoGxIITXEjUTjqFikMpHmwADrcxhoSl0JxGA4I5FoxCc9mIeJ4ugAIxgDAACi82AwYPCcBSuZp4cKrmKWYg8pjsYgOniCUSSWS6VSaXTNAzWJFmRLLdLZWdNLzFTghfoRTqGAqlarviBEVgoZTtW7xUhZdLZnLFSq1Zpo7HtR8-JSmgnjVLzamfSAoU1qKH0xGgZoNVqmYnEKnpVtdSAANaF6TupBt833NPhzNRmNxnXlgBWvaNEo70r+nd5-MFVZHGcjjfjfZbw+lggx5b9MAD6RDYa39fHOebxsXQ7zPO5ULoKJRQomIH7iGXh+PMF9W-X9-3NQRcXLStLlFH8WyPNlwMgsECxg+8JQgxCcU5csezQosMNxQ9vTBWc0OrK86ymW9JwInFk3A00a1HSNs0nZ9fW5f1AzAfZ0OwrDEEES0Tz5BgBR4vi6KEz1wNTfFGU0YlSXJB1aXpAhXT3Y1BFNQ8OwUm0VPtEBqXU51NJ1AMsAYDTGQo2sxx3fihJLeiHJYm9nI4kBeTfD9JNWCgOCAA) is what I am trying to do using the editor.

Comment: Hello, you're a TeX-SE member for more than 5 years now, so I assume that you know the essential rules on how to ask a question here. Your post is very messy hence not understandable. Please edit it accordingly. [TeX.SX starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That website is not a general TikZ editor, it's specifically a `tikz-cd` editor for making commutative diagrams. The code it generates makes use of the `tikz-cd` package, which you do not have in your preamble. Hence, all you need to do is to add

```
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
```

in the preamble